# Files Drag and drop using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am creating a website in php. Client demanded for drag and drop feature in image gallery so that
  he can just drag and drop images in gallery from anywhere.

Please suggest me some good site or code ?

Answer (score 1):

That is a feature of the browser, and your client can only use browsers that have this method implemented, such as Google Chrome and Firefox

It's called the **[File-API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/)** in **HTML5**

[Remmy Sharp](http://remysharp.com/) as a [nice example](http://html5demos.com/file-api) on it